# How to start a Selenium Firefox web browser minimized?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, web-scraping

My python script is in a loop and runs every half an hour, when ever the code runs it opens Firefox browser. So if I am working/ looking at any other screen all of a sudden the browser window pops up. I want my browser to either start minimized or disappear but my code should execute

```
while(True):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("http://iiitb.campusmetalink.com/cml/pages/setup/ModuleHome.jsf")
    driver.find_element_by_name("recqIDId:j_id15").send_keys("IIITB")
    driver.find_element_by_name("recqIDId:j_id17").send_keys("username")
    driver.find_element_by_name("recqIDId:j_id19").send_keys("password")
    driver.find_element_by_name("recqIDId:j_id25").click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="moduleForm:j_id40_body"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/a').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="scheduleForm:coltrm"]').send_keys("2016TERM2")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="scheduleForm:search"]').click()
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="scheduleForm:svres:tb"]/tr')
    if( len(elements) > 6):
        os.system("C:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.16/php C:/wamp64/www/srishti/space_auth/Source/Source_code/public/mail_includes.php")
    print elements
    driver.close()
    time.sleep(1800)
```

Comment: You should look into `PhantomJS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately selenium webdriver  does not provide any built in function  to minimize the window . 
However you can position your window out of sight by using below code.
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(-2000, 0));

Answer (score 0):

While Selenium does provide an inbuilt function to maximize the window, unfortunately it doesn't provide the same functionality to minimize the window.

The below code will move the browser window out of sight, but I don't know if this will fulfil your requirements.

`driver.set_window_position(0, 0)`

Comment: Should I import any thing for this It is saying invalid syntax at Point

Comment: this did not solve the problem I still get the pop up and once the browser is completely loaded then the position is being changed

Comment: I think the only other option would be to use PhantomJS rather than Firefox, as this will run headless. If you're not limited to using Firefox, switching to PhantomJS would probably be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

As other people already said: selenium webdriver does not provide any built in function to minimize the window BUT there are few roundabouts way to do it.
One of my favourite way is using win32gui and win32con:

```
import win32gui, win32con
win32gui.ShowWindow(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow(), win32con.SW_MINIMIZE)
```

The bad side of this code is, that the browser must be on the foreground.